# How would I solve Level 21 (endOfTheLine.js)?

Tags: untrusted

I have checked and checked, but I can't edit the code, and am 100% sure that no code is editable.

I'm truly stumped right now.

Any help/suggestions?

[image]

Comment: This site leads me to the absolute coolest of games sometimes, and other times I end up in Goat Simulator.

Comment: This question has exactly 21 votes, the same as the number of the level.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This one took me a bit of thinking.

Think hard about *why* you can't exit the level. There's nothing in the level code that stops you, so it must be coming from somewhere else.

Slightly further hint:

> There's also a `scripts/` folder in the menu.

Even further hint:

> You can edit the black sections of the scripts, same as you can for a level. Make sure you 'Execute' while in the script you've edited, not the level code. The script seems to revert if you change files.

Comment: And here I thought level 21 was just end of the game.  For those that still cannot figure it out, go to `objects.js` and remove the `if (!game.map.finalLevel)`

Comment: Please note you will not be able to pass this level in a normal Firefox environment. I imported the entire localStorage used by Untrusted into Chrome and continued to the next level.

Comment: @Octavian Are you modifying the actual game JavaScript? There's a way to do it in Firefox just fine.

Comment: @Halfwarr: You modify the game code via an in-game javascript editor, not via the web browser's development tools.

Comment: @Brian I'm aware I was confused by Octavian's comment

Comment: @Octavian's comment is that the final level doesn't work in Firefox, but it does work in Chrome. Rather than resolve the entire game in Chrome, he moved the local storage from Firefox to Chrome to continue playing.